# Discord.py How to make a command activate another command

Tags: discord.py

```
@commands.command(name="previous", aliases=["zurück"])
    async def previous_command(self, ctx, name: t.Optional[str]):
        player = self.get_player(ctx)
    
        if not player.queue.history:
            raise NoPreviousTracks

        player.queue.position -= 2
        await player.stop()


  @commands.command(name="playing", aliases=["np"])
    async def playing_command(self, ctx, name: t.Optional[str]):
        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        name = name or player.queue.current_track.title

        async with ctx.typing():
            async with aiohttp.request("GET", LYRICS_URL + name, headers={}) as r:
                if not 200 <= r.status <= 299:
                    raise NoLyricsFound
```

I have this code
How can I code something that says when the ,previous command gets activated the ,previous command  should activate the ,playing command too

i dont want to make it with aliases or something like that

I need a code that activtes the ,playing command when the ,previous command gets activated

Comment: Why the double post?

Comment: I think this one is more detailed so maybe there is a better solution for this code

Comment: It's the exact same post as [Discord.py How to make a command activate another command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940997/discord-py-how-to-make-a-command-activate-another-command)

Comment: My mistake sorry for the double post

Comment: But do you have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `self.playing_command(ctx, name)`, just like this :

```py
@commands.command(name="previous", aliases=["zurück"])
    async def previous_command(self, ctx, name: t.Optional[str]):
        player = self.get_player(ctx)
    
        if not player.queue.history:
            raise NoPreviousTracks

        player.queue.position -= 2
        await player.stop()
        self.playing_command(ctx, name)


  @commands.command(name="playing", aliases=["np"])
    async def playing_command(self, ctx, name: t.Optional[str]):
        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        name = name or player.queue.current_track.title

        async with ctx.typing():
            async with aiohttp.request("GET", LYRICS_URL + name, headers={}) as r:
                if not 200 <= r.status <= 299:
                    raise NoLyricsFound
```

But I don't really recommand to do this. You should make a pythonic function, which will be called by `playing_command` and `previous_command`.